# Group array elements based on value and get median of other value

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I'm trying to create a visualization based on the data from the Spotify [audio analysis](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#endpoint-get-audio-analysis).
Here is a part of the data:

```
{
  ...
  "segments": [
    {
      "start": 0,
      "duration": 0.20934,
      "confidence": 1,
      "loudness_start": -60,
      "loudness_max_time": 0.06898,
      "loudness_max": -22.328,
      "loudness_end": 0,
      ...
    },
    {
      "start": 0.20934,
      "duration": 0.10907,
      "confidence": 0.772,
      "loudness_start": -35.399,
      "loudness_max_time": 0.01327,
      "loudness_max": -25.11,
      "loudness_end": 0,
      ...
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

What I want to do:

1. Group these segments based on the start value. Example: All segments from second 0 to second 1 are a group, all segments from second 1 to second 2 and so on...
2. Every group should be a new object with all the values combined (e.g. the median of all `loudness_max` values, the median of all `loudness_start` values, etc...)

I already tried using `d3`s group and rollup functions but I couldn't get it to work so far. How would one achieve this using `js`/`d3`?

I hope this description is comprehensible, thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use `d3.bin()` to create buckets, and map the buckets to aggregate the properties with an aggregation function, such as `d3.median()`.

The `d3.bin()` method creates groups of data based on a given bucketing definition (d3 calls it `thresholds`). The output of `d3.bin()` is the same data you input, but with arrays around the buckets. For instance, an array `[0.2, 0.8, 1.2, 1.8]` binned in the thresholds `[0, 1, 2]` becomes `[ [0.2, 0.8], [1.2, 1.8] ]`.

You can use the `d3.bin().value()` method to specify an accessor, which in your case is a function that accesses the start property `d => d.start`.

Since you want the thresholds to be whole seconds, there are a few pre-processing calculations to compute the thresholds; I'll explain them in the comments of the following code snippet:

```js
    // Compute the max value of the data and round up to get the whole second.
    const maxValue = Math.ceil(d3.max(data, d=> d.start))
    
    // Define the bin thresholds (In your case, an array of whole seconds: 0, 1, ... , maxValue)
    const thresholds = d3.range(maxValue+1)

    // Define the min and max values of the buckets
    const domain = [0, maxValue]
    
    // Create the binner function 
    const binner = d3.bin().value(d=>d.start).thresholds(thresholds).domain(domain)

    // Bin the data
    const binned = binner(data)
    
    // Map each bin array and return
    const medians = binned.map(bin => {
        return {
          medianDuration: d3.median(bin, b=>b.duration),
          medianConfidence: d3.median(bin, b=>b.confidence),
            // ... The other properties repeat the same pattern

            /* You can also extract three additional values: the amount of data 
            in the bin, the start of the bin, and the end of the bin; */
          dataPoints: bin.length,
          bucketMin: bin.x0,
          bucketMax: bin.x1
      }
    })
```

Working example:

```js
const data = getData()
const maxValue = Math.ceil(d3.max(data, d=> d.start))

const thresholds = d3.range(maxValue+1)
const domain = [0, maxValue]

const binner = d3.bin().value(d=>d.start).thresholds(thresholds).domain(domain)
const binned = binner(data)

const medians = binned.map(bin => {
    return {
    medianDuration: d3.median(bin, b=>b.duration),
    dataPoints: bin.length,
    bucketMin: bin.x0,
    bucketMax: bin.x1

  }
})

console.log(medians)

function getData() {
  return [{
      "start": 0.2,
      "duration": 0.20934,
}, {
      "start": 0.8,
      "duration": 0.30934,
},
{
      "start": 1.2,
      "duration": 0.20934,
},
{
      "start": 1.8,
      "duration": 0.10934,
},
{
      "start": 2.2,
      "duration": 0.30934,
},
{
      "start": 2.8,
      "duration": 0.40934,
}]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```